# Emacs hangs after typing '/<anything>:' pattern

Tags: emacs

I am trying to connect to remote server by scp, but when I type `C-x C-f /myhost:` (no Enter pressing), emacs hangs for few minutes, then it allows to press Enter in minibuffer, and connects to host.

It *Messages* buffer it says:

```
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Making completion list...
```

Whatever I type in minibuffer between `/` and `:` - it makes emacs hang.

ssh and scp work fine, I tried to turn on and turn off ssh agent - it didn't help.
Yesterday everything worked fine, I haven't installed any packages or changed emacs configs.
How to debug it?

Comment: You haven't said which Emacs version you are using; the answer depends partly on this. Likely, Tramp tries something to complete. Set `tramp-verbose` to 6 (or to 10, if 6 isn't sufficient), and look what Tramp's doing.